# Flutter Bad State error but field does exist

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am getting the below error when trying to connect to a firebase database. I have checked that the database field names do exist:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#b3850):
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> StreamBuilder:file:///Users/username/AndroidStudioProjects/firestore_connection_test/lib/item_list.dart:26:13
```

This is the flutter code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Items'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          //Check error
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Some error occurred ${snapshot.error}'));
          }

          //Check if data arrived
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //get the data
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
            List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.docs;

            //Convert the documents to Maps
            List<Map> items = documents.map((e) =>
            {
              'name': e['name'],
            }).toList();

            //Display the list
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  //Get the item at this index
                  Map thisItem = items[index];
                  //Return the widget for the list items
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('${thisItem['name']}')
                  );
                });
          }

          //Show loader
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ), //Display a list // Add a FutureBuilder
    );
  }
```

I'm new to flutter but did try clearing the cache, clearing the build cache, running flutter clean, ran flutter doctor (all is ok) and I did reinstall flutter.

Comment: Inspect the contents of `e` within `documents.map((e) => {...}` and check if there is any document without the field "name"

Comment: Thank you - I've manually checked each document in Firestore (there are only 5 in my test) and each has a value for the name field. I'm not sure how to inspect the contents from within flutter (other than the way I tried which is causing an error)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
List<Map> items = documents.map((e) =>
        {
          'name': e.get('name'),
        }).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you Koffi but this is giving (sorry I can't seem to get line breaks to work):     lib/item_list.dart:44:28: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'dynamic Function(Object)'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
              'name': e.get['name'],
                           ^